# Magento Module is not responding to events

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.7

I have been scouring the web for solutions to the issue I have been having for 6 hours.

I am trying to create a Magento module that will respond to the customer logged in and registered events - sounds simple right.. apparently not for me :)

EDIT: I completely forgot to explain the issue... Anytime I log into an account the module is supposed to log the event in the system.log file in var/log. However, it never does. I know something is wrong with my code I just do not know what I am missing.

Here is some info on my files:

app/etc/modules/DigitalCK_all.xml

app/code/community/DigitalCK/PHPBB/etc/config.xml
app/code/community/DigitalCK/PHPBB/Model/Observer.php

notes: the module is currently in the community folder because I had some sliver of hope that moving it from local would fix the issue.. but rest assured it does not work in either directory...

file directories are all 644
folder directories are all 755
var and media directories are 777
Logging IS enabled

Magento version 1.7.0.2

Also... As I was following some magento tutorials I noticed that they never really worked for me.. ex: I would get 404 errors on routers because the "frontname wasn't attached to any modules" or whatever.

not sure if that provides any information.

seriously though any help is appreciated so much at this point.

Thanks.

**app/etc/modules/DigitalCK_all.xml**

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <DigitalCK_PHPBB>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
    </DigitalCK_PHPBB>
   </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/community/DigitalCK/PHPBB/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <DigitalCK_PHPBB>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </DigitalCK_PHPBB>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <PHPBB>
                <class>DigitalCK_PHPBB_Model</class>
            </PHPBB>
        </models>
    </global>


    <frontend>  
        <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <phpbb_login>
                        <class>digitalck_phpbb/observer</class>
                        <method>phpbbLogin</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </phpbb_login>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>           
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/community/DigitalCK/PHPBB/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php

class DigitalCK_PHPBB_Model_Observer 
{

    public function phpbbLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        Mage::log("customer Logged in");
    }

    public function phpbbRegister(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

issue in xml tag model name always be in  small letter tag.More details  please check in magento code  file "`Mage>Log>Config.xml`" here you find one eaxmple of customer_login event

```
<global>
        <models>
            <phpbb> <!-- model  name should be in small -->
                <class>DigitalCK_PHPBB_Model</class>
            </phpbb>
        </models>
    </global>


    <frontend>  
        <events>
        <customer_login>
            <observers>
                <phpbb_logins>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>phpbb/observer</class>
                    <method>phpbbLogin</method>
                </phpbb_logins>
            </observers>
        </customer_login>         
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I made the correction you mentioned, but the issue is still present. Also, Thanks for the reference to the mage>log>config.xml. I will look into that file.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I have solved this (with the help of Amit Bera)

in config.xml

BEFORE:

```
     <global>
        <models>
            <PHPBB>
                <class>DigitalCK_PHPBB_Model</class>
            </PHPBB>
        </models>
    </global>
```

AFTER:

```
 <global>
    <models>
        <digitalck_phpbb>
            <class>DigitalCK_PHPBB_Model</class>
        </digitalck_phpbb>
    </models>
</global>
```

The correction was made in the module name tag from just the module name to the namespace_module combination in all lowercase.

I hope this can help anyone else with similar issues.

Comment: but the code you posted in the question is equal to the code in the "AFTER" block. Did you edited the code in the question area?

Comment: Ah ya that's my fault, I changed it after Amit Bera's response so I could show others that I had made the change and so no one else thought that was the issue. I then forgot to change it back once I got the code working. I have reverted it back to the original post.